# postgresql: Update more than one record

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm writing an app which updates more than one record in postgresql database. 
I'm trying something like this:

```
UPDATE myDatabase SET internalNumber=30 WHERE id=10,12,13;
```

or like this:

```
UPDATE myDatabase SET internalNumber=30 WHERE id=10,id=12,id=13;
```

But nothing I've tried works. 
What can I do? 
Greetings, Rafał

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WHERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE myDatabase SET internalNumber=30 WHERE id IN (10, 12, 13)`